# linux/glibc. Can I use fprintf in signal handler?

Tags: linux, signals, handler, glibc

Can I use `fprintf(stderr)` in a signal (SIGALRM) handler with glibc/linux?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No you cannot. Check the manpage  [signal(7)](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html) for a list of async-signal-safe functions. `fprintf` is not included in that list.

If you don't need formatting then you can use `write(STDERR_FILENO, <buf>, <buflen>)` to write to stderr.

Comment: is it a list of functions from libc or list of kernel syscalls?

Comment: @osgx: link added to answer. It is a list of posix functions which also includes the libc standard. However, the libc standard does not require any libc function (except signal()) to be reentrant, therefore you cannot (portably) use any libc function inside a signal handler.

Answer (score 5):

This is not safe, quoting IBM DeveloperWorks article about [`Signal Handling Safety`](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-reent.html)

> Suppose the signal handler prints a message with fprintf and the program was in the middle of an fprintf call using the same stream when the signal was delivered. Both the signal handler's message and the program's data could be corrupted, because both calls operate on the same data structure: the stream itself.

Comment: glibc has a IO lock inside a FILE*. So, fprintf, which does interrupt a first fprintf will wait

Comment: @osgx: signal handlers aren't threads.  Waiting inside a signal handler is very bad news, because the thread holding the lock can't make progress until the signal handler completes.  So you have a deadlock.

Comment: @osgx: No, you didn't SAY "thread".  But you claimed that the lock helped by preventing corruption.  It won't.  The lock is designed to synchronize access between threads, not between a thread's main code and that same thread's signal handler.  Either you have a re-entrant lock, which has absolutely no effect on the signal handler and the corruption still occurs, or you have a non-reentrant lock, which causes deadlock.  In neither case does the presence of a lock inside `fprintf` in any way change the correct answer that "This is not safe."