# Is it safe to call fprintf() on a signal handler?

Tags: c, printf, signals, system-calls

In my programm i've something like this

```
#include "mylib.h"
void signalsHandler(int signum){
    switch(signum){
        case SIGUSR1:{
            //open file.txt with write(O_CREAT | O_APPEND)
            //call the function that use fprintf() and write on file.txt

        }
        default: {
            abort();
        }
    }
}
```

and the main is like

```
struct sigaction s;
memset(&s,0,sizeof(s));
s.sa_handler=signalsHandler;
s.sa_flags=SA_RESTART;
sigaction(SIGUSR1,&s,NULL);
```

It is safe to call a function on mylib.h that use fprintf() to write on a file? According to [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) I can only call write

Comment: No, it's not safe.

Comment: The documentation is clear, if `foo` is not is the list of async-signal-safe then it's not safe to call `foo` from a signal handler. However if you do so, your program still _might_ appear to work fine under certain conditions. Don't do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linux/glibc. Can I use fprintf in signal handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554129/linux-glibc-can-i-use-fprintf-in-signal-handler)

Comment: you might also be interested in : [How to avoid using printf in a signal handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler)

Comment: [Per the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188): "Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions."  POSIX provides guarantees that you can call **some/a few** functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fprintf` is **not** safe to call in a signal handler, due in part to the buffering capabilities for `FILE` objects.

What you *should* do is set a global flag in the signal handler, then check that flag elsewhere in your code and act accordingly.